# How to list a post under an author's archive page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin which lists the author and its contributors in custom post meta-box. So what happens so far is when a user clicks the author name, it gives authors archive page which lists all the posts by author. So how can I list that same post in contributor's archive page?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a `meta_query`.
I am assuming on contributor archive page you can able to get contributor ID.

Now suppose you store your post meta like
meta_key = 'contributor_id'; and
meta_value = '2' //ID of contributor

So now

```
$args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'contributor_id',
           'value' => '2',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
print_r($query);
```

above code will return all the posts which belongs to that specific contributor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible automatically. 
On WordPress every post has one and only author, so in the archive page of that author you'll have only his/her posts.

Maybe you could implement a widget/plugin to show "related posts"